# how to replace the N nlargest values for the sume of those N largests values in a DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a given df, I would like to get the nlargest (N) values for each row and replace them with the nlargest(N).sum() value. Basically find the columns where the N max values are present and replace them with their addition if the value in those N largest cells is >= [nlargest().sum/N].

The following df is a reduced example:

```
data = [[1, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.1], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0], [4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  [5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4,  0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", 'S1', "S2", 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6'])
df.set_index('ID', inplace =True)
df
```

I think i could do something like this:

```
#get the df.nlargest(N).sum() 

N =3 #number of largest values

df['nlargestsum'] = df.apply(lambda s: s.abs().nlargest(N).sum(), axis=1)
```

it produces this output:

```
data = [[1, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9], [2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.9], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0.6], [4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  [5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4,  0, 0, 0.9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", 'S1', "S2", 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'nlargestsum'])
df.set_index('ID', inplace =True)
df
```

so far so good, but is form here where I'm struggling how to produce the following output:

```
data = [[1, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9], [2, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.9], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0.6], [4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  [5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9,  0, 0, 0.9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", 'S1', "S2", 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'nlargestsum'])
df.set_index('ID', inplace =True)
df
```

as you can see for ID 2, columns S1:S3, the original value changed for the nlargestsum value, because 0.3 >= 0.9/3. However for the ID 5, columns S1 & S2 the value remains the same (< 0.9/3) but the values in ID5 S3 & S4 changed because 0.4 > 0.9/3. Same for ID3, the values in S4 & S5 are changed to 0.6 each.

i would appreciate some insides and ideas!

Comment: For ID3 are values changed?

Comment: yes! sorry i just corrected the question!

Answer (score 0):

##### replacing values

Using numpy:

```
cols = df.filter(like='S').columns

a = df[cols].to_numpy()
mask = np.argsort(-a) < N

a[mask] = np.repeat((a[mask].reshape(-1, N)).sum(1), N)

df[cols] = a
```

output:

```
     S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6  nlargestsum
ID                                           
1   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0          0.9
2   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.1          0.9
3   0.0  0.0  0.6  0.6  0.6  0.0          0.6
4   1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0          1.0
5   0.9  0.1  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.0          0.9
```

##### older answer

With numpy:

```
N = 3
df['nlargestsum'] = (np.sort(df.to_numpy())[:, -N:]).sum(1)

# or, to limit to the "S" columns
# df['nlargestsum'] = (np.sort(df.filter(like='S').to_numpy())[:, -N:]).sum(1)
```

You can also use:

```
N = 3
df['nlargestsum'] = (df#.filter(like='S') # uncomment to restrict to the "S" columns
                       .stack().sort_values()
                       .groupby(level=0)
                       .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-N:].sum())
                    )
```

output:

```
     S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6  nlargestsum
ID                                           
1   0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0          0.9
2   0.3  0.3  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.1          0.9
3   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.4  0.0          0.6
4   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0          1.0
5   0.1  0.1  0.4  0.4  0.0  0.0          0.9
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! that's a good option for the first part of the question... but my real problem is the final output of my question. the selective changing of the nlargest(N) values for the the nlargestsum values under a condition in the entire dataframe.

Comment: @Luis I see, sorry, check the update

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#filter only S columns
df1 = df.filter(like='S')
#compare for greater or equal by division nlargestsum with N and if match replace values
df.update(df1.mask(df1.ge(df['nlargestsum'].div(N), axis=0), df['nlargestsum'], axis=0))
print (df)
     S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6  nlargestsum
ID                                           
1   0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0          0.9
2   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.1          0.9
3   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.6  0.0          0.6
4   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0          1.0
5   0.1  0.1  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.0          0.9
```